# increment row number with laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

How to make increment row number with laravel pagination ? When i use pagination and i go to page 2 and above it will back to beginning. for example i will paginate(3)

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>No</th>
       <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($telephone->results as $telp)
    <tr>
       <td>
         {{$i++}}
       </td>
       <td>{{ $telp->name }}</td>                               
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

when i go to page 2 the number will start from 1 again.

i need to make it when i go to page 2 it will start from 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the `getFrom` method to get the starting number of the current pages results. So instead of setting `$i = 1;` you should be able to do this.

```php
<?php $i = $telephone->getFrom(); ?>
```

---

In Laravel 3 there is no `getFrom` method so you need to calculate it manually.

```php
<?php $i = ($telephone->page - 1) * $telephone->per_page + 1; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention. By the way when I use getForm method i get error Call to undefined method Laravel\Paginator::getFrom()

Comment: Ah sorry, assumed L4. I've updated my answer to include an L3 variation.

Answer (score 30):

In Laravel 5.3 you can use [firstItem()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_firstItem):

```
@foreach ($items as $key => $value)    
  {{ $items->firstItem() + $key }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 15):

The below works with laravel 5.4

```
<?php $i = ($telephone->currentpage()-1)* $telephone-
>perpage() + 1;?>
@foreach($telephone as $whatever)
<td> {{ $i++ }}</td>
@endforeach
```

**Edited**
The below works for laravel 5.7 above

```
@foreach ($telephone as $key=> $whatever)
  <td>{{ $key+ $telephone->firstItem() }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 7):

Laravel 5.3

```
@foreach ($products as $key=>$val)
  {{ ($products->currentpage()-1) * $products->perpage() + $key + 1 }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 6.2:
$loop - just in case, is a built-in instance in Blade

```
@foreach($array as $item)
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="site-id">
         {{($array->currentPage() - 1) * $array->perPage() + $loop->iteration}}
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the following line

```
$i = ($telephone->currentpage()-1)* $telephone->perpage();
```

in place of

```
$i = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@php($sl = ($yourVariable->perPage() * $yourVariable->currentPage()) - ($yourVariable->perPage() - 1))

@foreach($yourVariable as $item)

<td>{{ $item->key_name }}</td>

.....

@php($sl++)

@endforeach
```

Comment: you should explain the answer

Answer (score 1):

**In Laravel 6**

```
@php $i = ($data->currentpage()-1)* $data->perpage() + 1;@endphp

@foreach($data as $banner)
 <tr>
   <td>{{$i}}</td>
   <td><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/dist/img/{{$banner->name}}" height="250" width="600"></td>
 </tr>
 @php  $i += 1; @endphp
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel Pagination. It works very well

The backend

```
public function index()
{
    return view('your.telephone.index', [
        'telephone' => Telephone::paginate(15)
    ]);
}
```

Blade front end

```
<td>{{ (($telephone->currentPage() * 10) - 10) + $loop->iteration  }}</td>
```

And don't forget embed the page

```
{{ $telephone->links() }}
```

For `$loop->iteration`

See the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable

For `$telephone->currentPage()`

See the doc here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this, in Laravel 8, accessing $loop, and links()->paginator:

```
       @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{ ($users->currentPage() - 1)  * $users->links()->paginator->perPage() + $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{$user->name}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Which works properly even when the final page is only partially filled.

Could also use $users->perPage() in place of $users->links()->paginator->perPage()

Answer (score 0):

Or avoid php tags completely by

```
 @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
    {{ (Input::get('page', 1) - 1) * $users->getPerPage() + $key + 1 }}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in your controller. example given below

```
$records = Table::paginate(20);
return view('yourview',compact('records')->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 20);
```

**Note:** paginate value must be equal to with() function vlaue

after that you can use $i variable in you blade file. controller calculate value according to page number and return to blade

In blade file. use inside the loop

```
{{ ++$i }}
```

Hopefully this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8++

`$loop->iteration` is available out of the box inside loop.

```
{{ ($barangs->currentPage() - 1)  * $barangs->count() + $loop->iteration }}
```

Comment: `$barangs->count()` should be `$barangs->perPage()`. `count()` is for the current page, which will cause issues if you're on the last page and it has a different number of results from the others pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Product::paginate(); // ProductController  
    

// product/index.blade.php

@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
  <td>
    {{($products->currentPage() - 1)  * $products->perPage() + $loop->iteration}}
  </td>
<tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Add some explanation with code, so that it can help others too for the same or similar problem. A comment has been added as part of the review.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($showUserData as $key => $data) {
 <tr>
 <td>{{$showUserData->firstItem() + $key}}</td>
</tr>
}
@endforeach
```

This will give you the sequence you need. It starts from 1 and on next page from the last record +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
 $i = ($users->currentPage() - 1) * $users->perPage() + 1;
@endphp
```

using laravel new